# Update Phone number on Google Apps user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

Hi im using Advanced Services in Google Apps Script.

Im trying to add a number to the users profile.

```
var userValue = 'test@company.com';
 var phoneValue = 017236233;

  var users = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userValue);

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

     AdminDirectory.Users.update(users[i].phones[].primary, phoneValue);

  }
```

The last part is the one i am not certain on. It fails with "Syntax error. (line 22, file "Code")"

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the autocomplete on the update method you have to give it a [User resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) and a userKey (the user primary e-mail).

[image: Admin SDK Apps Script autocomplete]

So this line of code should be:

```
AdminDirectory.Users.update(userResource, userPrimaryEmail);
```

Since you just want to add a phone your User resource can only contain this:

```
var userResource = {
    phones:[{
        value: phoneValue
    }]
}
```

However be aware that this would update the whole list of phones and overwrite older values.

Also, note that the get method your are using doesn't return a list of User resources but a single User resource. You could use that same resource, update it and send it back.

So what you're looking would be:

```
var userPrimaryEmail = 'test@company.com';
var phoneValue = 017236233;

var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userPrimaryEmail);

// If user has no phones add a 'phones' empty list to the user resource
if (! user.phones){
  user.phones = [];
}

user.phones.push(
  {
     value: phoneValue,
     type: "mobile" // Could be 'home' or 'work' of whatever is allowed  
  }
)

AdminDirectory.Users.update(user, userPrimaryEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

A syntax error means that the code you wrote isn't valid. More information on syntax errors is available on the [Apps Script troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#syntax_errors).